# Fill remaining space by increasing font

Tags: css

I have an issue where I want to fill the remaining (very dynamic) space of the box by increasing (and decreasing) the font size as much as possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/urqL1evn/2

Right now, all i have is:

```
.textbox {
  margin: 0 5em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

The page will be viewed on a 1920x1080 50" TV with 100% windows scaling.

I will add and remove sections to the point where there will only be one on the screen and maximum 4.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: So you want to have this text always fitting to the boxes to avoid scrolling on them right?

Comment: this is not a CSS job.:)

Comment: Maybe http://fittextjs.com/ can help, but it's only for width I believe and not height.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.textbox').each(function() {
        let that = $(this),
            textBoxHeight = parseInt(that.height()) + 20, // +20 its sum of margin-top + margin-bottom  of .textbox element
            parentHeight = parseInt(that.parent().height()),
            fontSize = parseInt(that.css('font-size'))

        while(textBoxHeight > parentHeight)
        {
            fontSize -= 1
            that.css({'font-size':fontSize+'px'})
            textBoxHeight = parseInt(that.height()) + 20 // +20 its sum of margin-top + margin-bottom of .textbox element
        }
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urqL1evn/21/

CSS has changed (margin in em > px)

```
.textbox {
    margin: 10px 20px;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 100px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

So you need to set `.textbox` `font-size` to `100px` and then in JS we're lowering it down all the time until height of `.textbox` element is not equal or lower than it's parent element. It's very simple and it works just fine.

I hope this is answer for your question.

Don't forget to use jQuery library.